# Error: Constructor Room in class Room cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, inheritance

I am completely new to java. I have searched for hours upon hours for the solution to this problem but every answer involves passing args or using a void which I do not do in this situation.

I have two java files, one for Room class, and one for TourHouse class. I am trying to create a new Room in the TourHouse class. Here is my error, it's driving me nuts, I've tried everything I am capable of understanding. Thank you in advance.

```
HouseTour.java:15: error: constructor Room in class Room cannot be applied to given
types;
     {
     ^
required: String, String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal arguments differ in length
```

Here is the Room class, will have 7 rooms total once I can figure this out

```
// Room.java

import java.util.*;

public class Room
{
    // Define Instance Variables
    private String name;
    private String description;

    // Define Constructor
    public Room(String theName, String theDescription)
    {
        name = theName;
        description = theDescription;
    }

    public String toString( )
    {
    return "The " + name + "\n" + description + "\n";
    }
}
```

Here is the HouseTour class

```
import java.util.*;

public class HouseTour extends Room
{
    // Define Variables
    public Room[ ] rooms = new Room[7];

    //Define Constructor
    public HouseTour( )
    {
    rooms[0] = new Room("Living Room", "Mayonnaise and Brill Grates, Michaelsoft");

    rooms[1] = new Room("Basement", "Hopefully no dead bodies down here...");
    }

    // this is horrible and not right 
    public String rooms( ) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++)
        {
            String output = "House Rooms included in tour\n";
            String output2 = output + rooms.toString() + "\n";
            return output2;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Solved but still need help here because I am complete n00b,  :(**

```
    // this is horrible and not right 
    public String rooms( ) 
    {
        output = "House Rooms included in tour\n";
        for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++)
        {
            output += rooms[i]; // I can't do this but how do i?
        }
        return output.toString(); // do I do this?
    }
}
```

What I am doing is trying to learn java by converting the ruby projects I have created. So in ruby you say:

```
def rooms
  output = "House Rooms included in tour\n"
  @rooms.each do |r|
    output += r.to_s + "\n"
  end
  return output
end
```

---

**Edit: Still trying, any ideas?**
added public String s; and public String output; to declarations

```
    // this is horrible and not right 
    public String rooms( ) 
    {
        s = ""
        output = "House Rooms included in tour\n";
        for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++)
        {
            s += rooms[i];
        }
        s.toString() // I don't know
        return output + s; // do I do this?
    }
}
```

---

**Edit: Solved thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels**

Comment: This will give you ugly output: `rooms.toString()`, but I don't see your error. Which line of code is giving the error since I don't see it up there?

Comment: Yea, I'm struggling with the output now, still learning, I thought that would work but alas, it does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see your problem: HouseTour extends Room. Don't do this! HouseTour is not a more specific case of a Room type and so should not extend this class. It does not fulfill the "is-a" rule, and would be similar to trying to define Bus as a child class of SchoolKid. Just like a Bus isn't a type of SchoolKid but rather contains SchoolKids, a HouseTour isn't a Room but rather contains Rooms. It fulfills the ***has-a*** relationship, not the ***is-a*** relationship.

If the inheritance were proper in this situation, your HouseTour constructor would need to call the Room super constructor and pass in two String parameters:

```
// Don't do this!!!
public class HouseTour extends Room {

    public HouseTour() {
      super("foo", "bar");
      ....
    }
```

But having said that, again inheritance is not proper here -- just get rid of `extends Room`, and you're home free.

e.g.,

```
public class HouseTour {  // no extends!
  private Room[] rooms; // has-a not is-a

  public HouseTour() {
    // don't call super here
  }
```

Also, as per my comment, this will give you ugly output: `rooms.toString()`

Instead iterate through the Array and get the toString() result from each Room item in the array.

---

**Edit**
Suggestions on your rooms() method:

- Create a String or StringBuilder **before** the loop.
- Build up the String or StringBuilder **inside** the loop.
- Return the String or StringBuilder#toString **after** the loop.
- Inside of the loop get the toString() from the current Room item in the list.
- You will need to check that the rooms[i] item isn't null before calling a method on it.

---

**Edit 2**

You state that this:

```
public String rooms( ) 
{
    output = "House Rooms included in tour\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++)
    {
        output += rooms[i]; // I can't do this but how do i?
    }
    return output.toString(); // do I do this?
}
```

is causing problems, but you don't specify the problem.

Myself, I'd do something like:

```
public String rooms( ) {
    // declare your String locally, not globally in the class
    String output = "House Rooms included in tour\n";
    // again, avoid using "magic" numbers like 7
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
        output += rooms[i].toString(); // **** you must extract Room's String
    }
    return output;  // no need to call toString() on a String
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's how I learned so that really sucks, completely misunderstood, thank you so much, I mean I spent 4 hours trying to fix that, #AmateurProblems?

Comment: @thewrp: no problem. Remember to always keep in mind the `is-a` vs `has-a` difference. HouseTours ***has*** Room objects, but doesn't fulfill the ***is-a*** Room object.

Comment: Is there any chance you can elaborate on what I am doing wrong in my publc String() rooms method? I just tried to compile and realized that will not work at all.

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot, thanks for your help, so create 
String s = ""
run the loop
s += rooms + "\n";
end loop
return s;

Comment: @thewrp: almost. not rooms + "\n" -- you need the array index to get the ith Room item held by rooms. Also, avoid "magic numbers", such as `<= 7`. Instead always try to let Java decide how many times to loop ... `< rooms.length`.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful, do you have a link or a search term I could use to show me an example, I tried looking up StringBuilder and that's wayy over my head right now, every example I have in my book is showing a return, nothing where you would concat then return outside loop :(

Comment: @thewrp: for your purposes, a String will work just fine and a StringBuilder would be premature optimization, though later you will want to learn to use it since it is more efficient. Just remember to use the array items inside the loop. `myArray[i]`.

Comment: alright, this is driving me nuts, I just am confused, your hints have been helpful but I can't get it right, any chance you can look at my edit? I just want to learn, can't find good examples online :(

Comment: even if i try string s = "", s = rooms[i], then s.toString() after loop it no work, I don't even know

Comment: @thewrp: Please edit your original question similar to how I've edited my answer. Don't change your original post or code, as doing this will invalidate any answers present, but add to the bottom your latest code attempt and problems you're having with it, and then notify any folks who have commented or answered about the changes.

Comment: @thewrp: I see you've done this. Where do you declare the output as a String variable? You can't use a variable until you declare it: `String output = "";` And there's no need to call `toString()` on a String.

Comment: Did I misuse edit? I am all new to this, I've been learning out of books, I figured I have to ask someone for help. All the examples I can find don't use the method I use, if I declare public String output; in beginning that doesn't solve it, I don't know what to do

Comment: Alright, thanks I'm going to try that, I accidentally posted i <= 7, it is not that, if this works thank you so much, this is all new to me

Comment: Thank you so much, how could I forget to declare String, man it's going to be a long learning process. I can't thank you enough!!!!!!!